# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') when trying to access a screen from the header of a bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to implement a navigation button inside the header of a bottom tab navigator from react-navigation as such :

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
        <Stack.Navigator>

          <Stack.Screen 
          name="AppName"
          component={BottomTabNavigator}
          options={{
            headerRight: () => (
              <Button title="Profil" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profil')}/>
            ),
          }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen 
          name="Profil"
          component={ProfileScreen}          
          />
```

However, I am getting the error mentioned in the title. I have read documentation about it and I believe that it can't navigate to this screen because it is not nested in the bottom tab navigator. I couldn't find a way to put the profile screen inside of the bottom tab navigator without actually displaying it in the bottom tab.
Should I go even further into trying to add the screen to the bottom tab without displaying it (if it is possible), or is there any better options ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the useNavigation hook of the native stack navigator to navigate from the navigator component to nested screens.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <Button
            title="Back"
            onPress={() => {
                navigation.goBack();
            }}
       />
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer ! What are the navigation props that I have to get for this to work exactly ?

Comment: Almost all the navigation options refer to the current rendered screen. you also can use the console.log to see all the navigation options.

Comment: I managed to make it work thanks to you ! You helped me a great deal thanks again !